# What does pipe symbol mean?

Tags: haskell

The following is the haskell comprehensions, what I don't understand is the pipe symbol. What does it mean and what is its role in the function?

```
boomBangs xs = [ if x < 10 then "BOOM!" else "BANG!" | x <- xs, odd x]

ghci> let xxs = [[1,3,5,2,3,1,2,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],[1,2,4,2,1,6,3,1,3,2,3,6]]  

ghci> [ [ x | x <- xs, even x ] | xs <- xxs] 

[[2,2,4],[2,4,6,8],[2,4,2,6,2,6]]
```

Comment: Do you mean "pipe"? And have you read a tutorial on comprehensions? Any decent guide will surely cover this.

Answer (score 4):

Its expression/syntax for list comprehensions. An easy example is the following,

```
import Data.Char (toUpper)
[toUpper c | c <- s]
```

You pass a string (list of chars), [ s ],  "Hello", to the generator [ c <- s ] , this feeds each character of s to the left-hand expression [ toUpper c ], building a new list. The result of this list comprehension would be "HELLO".

Comment: this notation is heavily inspired by mathematical set notation see https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/19e5efdbd0e7c51808d2a463128b2cdf2afb8ff4 (definition of a torus).